# How do I move a camera to a new X and Y position when the player collides with a certain object?

Tags: camera, game-maker

The lowdown is this: I'm making a 2D overhead game that takes place in separate screens in a room. Each screen is separated by a few blocks of black space (to give the impression of screens being separate rooms) and a rectangular "transition block" in doorways. My idea is, once a player touches this block, they are moved to the next adjacent screen *along* with the camera **instantly**.

I can move a player to the next screen this way, the big hangup that I'm having is moving the camera as well. I want every collision box to have the coordinates needed to set the camera around the next screen once player-box collision happens, similar to the setup I have with the player character.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is, upon collision, change [view_visible](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/windows%20and%20views/views/view_visible.html). You can set up 8 different views in the room editor, but it sounds like you want to set the new view in the player-box collision object which can be done with [room_set_view](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/rooms/room_set_view.html).